# How to check if a MultiValueDictionary contains a specific value

Tags: c#

[MultiValueDictionary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/05/multidictionary-becomes-multivaluedictionary.aspx) is an experimental implementation of a multi-value dictionary in c#. It allows you to have multiple values per key. I need help creating code that works like,
*(If MultiValueDictionary contains value "pudding", then do this)*. Here is a code example of what I need:

Class field declaration:

```
public MultiValueDictionary<string, string> _cookBook = new MultiValueDictionary<string, string>();
```

Then using in some method:

```
_cookBook.Add("food", "icing");
_cookBook.Add("food", "pudding");
_cookBook.Add("dessert", "pudding");
if(_cookBook.Contains("pudding"))
{ 
   //Do this
}
```

MultiValueDictionary is available through NuGet as Microsoft.Experimental.Collections. Since this is a relatively new type of dictionary, I'm not finding a lot of information on it. Any help on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that as usual:

```
//If you know item key and value
if (_cookBook.Contains("food", "icing"))
{
    //Do something
}

//If you know item key
if (_cookBook.ContainsKey("food"))
{
    //Do something
}

//If you know item value
if (_cookBook.ContainsValue("icing"))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Tested with [Microsoft Experimental Collections 1.0.3-alpha](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/)